# Как получить поиск в массиве по имени и фамилии?

Tags: java

Вопрос: как получить поиск по массиву с именем и фамилией введенных пользователем с консоли? На данный момент ищет только по имени, а как сделать  по имени и фамилии?

```
package javaapplication10;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
   String[] inp  = new String[1];

   String numbers [][] = {
       {"Galina", "Pupkina", "555-3322"},
       {"Andrey", "Pupkin", "555-8976"},
       {"Alex", "Pupkin", "555-1037"},
       {"Masha", "Pupkina", "555-1400"}           
   } ;

 int i;
 System.out.print("Введите Имя : ");

  inp[0] = myScanner.next();
 if(inp.length != 1) System.out.println("Введите Имя и Фамилию");
 else {
     for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
         if(numbers[i][0].equals(inp[0])){
             System.out.println(numbers[i][0]+ ": " + numbers[i][1]);
             break;
         }
     }
 if(i == numbers.length) System.out.println("Не найдено.");
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
package javaapplication10;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inp  = new String[2];

        String numbers [][] = {
                {"Galina", "Pupkina", "555-3322"},
                {"Andrey", "Pupkin", "555-8976"},
                {"Alex", "Pupkin", "555-1037"},
                {"Masha", "Popova", "555-1400"}
        } ;

        int i;
        System.out.print("Введите Имя : ");

        inp[0] = myScanner.next();
        System.out.print("Введите Фамилию : ");
        inp[1] = myScanner.next();

//        if(inp.length != 1) System.out.println("Введите Имя и Фамилию");
//        else {
          for(i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
              if((numbers[i][1].equals(inp[1])) && (numbers[i][0].equals(inp[0]))) {
                      System.out.println(numbers[i][0]+ ": " + numbers[i][1]);
                  break;
              }
          }
              if(i == numbers.length) System.out.println("Не найдено.");
//        }

    }
}
```

Я модифицировал Ваше решение.Получилось то, что Вы хотели?

Comment: да спасибо все верно

Answer (score 2):

В java принято писать в объектном стиле

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class User {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String phone;

    User(String name, String surname, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}

public class JavaApplication10 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            users.add(new User("Galina", "Pupkina", "555-3322"));
            users.add(new User("Andrey", "Pupkin", "555-8976"));
            users.add(new User("Alex", "Pupkin", "555-1037"));
            users.add(new User("Masha", "Popova", "555-1400"));

            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Введите Имя : ");
            String name = myScanner.next();

            System.out.print("Введите Фамилию : ");
            String surname  = myScanner.next();

            boolean isFound = false;
            for (User user : users) {
                if (user.name.equals(name) && user.surname.equals(surname)) {
                    isFound = true;
                    System.out.println("Найден " + user.name + " " + user.surname);
                }
            }

            if(!isFound) System.out.println("Не найдено.");
    }
}
```

Так намного читабельней

Comment: да это тоже хороший вариант...